# Getting an error message after installing a new update of eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I updated from eclipse 06-2019 to eclipse 06-2021 today and I have run into various problems.

The first thing that happened was that my JVM version needed to be updated from version 8 to a version 11 or higher. So I downloaded version 11 and restarted my computer and then opened up eclipse and I get this error message. Can someone help me fix this problem? I saw someone have this problem 8 years ago but the message that I receive is a little different from the one that the post had. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9l36.png)

Comment: Looks like you picked a 32-bit version of Java. That won't work with a 64-bit version of Eclipse.

Comment: What a pity that you missed updating for so long, so you didn't get the Java included in Eclipse that would have been the right one. Consider a fresh installation.